# User input to call an object Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make a program that takes a user input and calls the corresponding object and its values.

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: findStudent is not defined

HTML:

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name">
<button type = "submit" id = "submit" onclick = "findStudent()">Find Student </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function Student(GPA, Faculty, Major) {
  this.GPA = GPA;
  this.Faculty = Faculty;
  this.Major = Major;
}

var Matthew = new Student(5.0, "Science", "Cognitive Systems");
var Rohit = new Student(5.0, "Science", "Micro Biology");
var Marcel = new Student(5.0, "Engineering", "Undeclared");
var Louie = new Student(5.0, "Engineering", "Mechanical");
var Matt = new Student(5.0, "Engineering", "Mechanical");
var Petra = new Student(5.0, "Science", "Biology");
var Senara = Senny = new Student(5.0, "Science", "Biology");
var Jen = Jenny = Jennifer = new Student(5.0, "Science", "BioChemistry");
var Julia = Jules = new Student(5.0, "???", "Life");

findStudent function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('name').innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Please learn to look in the debug console to see your own Javascript errors.  There is no reason to come here for an issue that the debug console will spell out for you.  This is part of learning how to troubleshoot your own code.

Comment: i think it should be "function findStudent() {"